# os.listdir showing 25000 inputs but only able to load 10685 files

Tags: python, listdir

```
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array

filePath = 'PetImages/'
photos, labels = list(), list()

width = 100
height = 100
counter = 0


for folder in os.listdir(filePath):
    main = os.listdir(filePath + folder)
    for file in os.listdir(filePath + folder):
        print(filePath + folder)
        counter = counter + 1
        try:
            if folder == 'Cat':
                output = 1.0
            else:
                output = 0.0
            photo = load_img(filePath + folder + '/' + file, target_size=(width,height))
            photo = img_to_array(photo)
            photos.append(photo)
            labels.append(output)
        except:
            break
    
photos = np.asarray(photos)
labels = np.asarray(labels)
print(photos.shape, labels.shape)

#np.save('CatDogPhotos.npy', photos)
#np.save('CatDogLabels.npy', labels)
```

Output:
(10685, 100, 100, 3) (10685,)

I am trying to load the typical Cat/Dog dataset. However, with this code, I am only able to load an array of 10685 photos instead of all 25000 images.

I am not able to figure out why this is the case. Can anyone help to comment on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have `except: break`. Maybe you hit an exception?

Comment: Try changing `except: break` to `except: continue` and see if that increases the size of your output. Or try putting a print statement after `except` to see if it's being triggered. As @drum points out, any exception breaks out of your for loop